# How to prevent CheckBox getting clicked while ComboBox is closed?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a `ComboBox` which has a `CheckBox` control as a DataTemplate, and with that when the user tries to open ComboBox they sometimes accidentally end up selecting/deselecting the `ComboBox`, So what I want to do is to disable that behavior and open the `ComboBox` menu instead.

My `ComboBox` looks something as below:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve that? I tried modifying `ItemTemplate` of the `ComboBox` but so far didn't find any solution for it.

For now what I can do is just to bind CheckBox `IsEnabled` property with ComboBox `IsDropDownOpen` property, but if there's any better solution which you can suggest would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe some way to avoid the CheckBox IsChecked state change if the combobox is not Open. Or Disable the CheckBox if combobox is not Open?

Comment: @Tony. Thanks. I updated my post with the workaround I am using right now, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of toggling **IsEnabled** you should toggle [IsHitTestVisible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.ishittestvisible) property of your checkbox. So when it is set to false it will not receive any mouse click events, but it will still look enabled because it still can receive keyboard events. So if you use tab navigation to tap it then it would work.

Comment: That's the point of using `IsEnabled`, I don't want to have any inputs neither from mouse nor from the keyboard or any other possible inputs. As far as look and feel is concern, I will update the CheckBox styling so that it does not look likes it's disabled even though it is.

Comment: yeah then that is ur only option , just toggle isenabled and update the disabled style so that it looks same as enabled.